# Conversation with a specific user

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

How can i get conversation of a specific user from my inbox using the uid of the user with fql query or multi-query?
For Example: if i want conversation between user X with uid=786758454 and me?

something like this

```
SELECT message_id, thread_id, author_id, body, created_time, viewer_id 
FROM message WHERE thread_id IN 
(SELECT thread_id, subject, recipients FROM thread WHERE folder_id =0 )
AND author_id = 'user X uid' ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 0,25
```

Comment: I need the 'body' of the message for both me and user x !

Answer (score 0):

You need the both user id. The user X uid and your uid. Try using this fql query:

```
SELECT message_id, thread_id, author_id, body, created_time, viewer_id FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0) and (author_id = 'user X uid' or author_id = 'YOUR user uid') ORDER BY created_time DESC
```

Hope this can solve your problem.